# How to add emails to contact lists in SendGrid with Node?

Tags: node.js, react-native, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I'm working on a React Native app with Firebase Functions. I am unable to add new contacts to a SendGrid list consistently.

This is my function:

```
 exports.addToSendGridMembersList = functions.https.onCall(async (data) => {
  const {first, last, email} = data
  p(first,last,email)

  const axios = require('axios');

  let e = JSON.stringify(email)
  let f =  JSON.stringify(first)
  let l = JSON.stringify(last)

  p("JSON.stringify: ", e, f, l)

  axios({
    method: "PUT",
    url: "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts",
    headers: 
    { 'content-type': 'application/json',
      authorization: 'Bearer ' + SEND_GRID_KEY },
    body: 
      { "list_ids": [ 
        "eda0bc01-b098-4366-ad58-8bab03ec9b33" 
      ],
      "contacts": [
        {
          "email": "o@gmail.com",
          "first_name": "o",
          "last_name": "o"
        }
      ]
    }
  })
    .then(function (error, response, body) {
      console.log(error)
      console.log(response)
      console.log(body);
    })
});
```

I at first thought the axios body was unable to read constants that's why I stringified them and was going to insert them in the body (first, last and email) values. This is the response I get in Google Cloud logs

```
JSON.stringify: "gg@gmail.com" "gg" "gg"
> Unhandled error { Error: Request failed with status code 400 at createError (/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15) at settle (/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12) at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/workspace/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11) at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15) at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:466:23) at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) config: { url: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts', method: 'put', headers: { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', authorization: 'Bearer HIDDEN', 'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.1' }, transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ], transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ], timeout: 0, adapter: [Function: httpAdapter], xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN', xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN', maxContentLength: -1, maxBodyLength: -1, validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus], body: { list_ids: [Array], contacts: [Array] }, data: undefined }, request: ClientRequest { domain: Domain { domain: null, _events: [Object], _eventsCount: 3, _maxListeners: undefined, members: [], [Symbol(kWeak)]: WeakReference {} }, _events: [Object: null prototype] { socket: [Function], abort: [Function], aborted: [Function], connect: [Function], error: [Function], timeout: [Function], prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish] }, _eventsCount: 7, _maxListeners: undefined, output: [], outputEncodings: [], outputCallbacks: [], outputSize: 0, writable: true, _last: true, chunkedEncoding: false, shouldKeepAlive: false, useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true, sendDate: false, _removedConnection: false, _removedContLen: false, _removedTE: false, _contentLength: 0, _hasBody: true, _trailer: '', finished: true, _headerSent: true, socket: TLSSocket { _tlsOptions: [Object], _secureEstablished: true, _securePending: false, _newSessionPending: false, _controlReleased: true, _SNICallback: null, servername: 'api.sendgrid.com', alpnProtocol: false, authorized: true, authorizationError: null, encrypted: true, _events: [Object], _eventsCount: 9, connecting: false, _hadError: false, _handle: [TLSWrap], _parent: null, _host: 'api.sendgrid.com', _readableState: [ReadableState], readable: true, domain: [Domain], _maxListeners: undefined, _writableState: [WritableState], writable: false, allowHalfOpen: false, _sockname: null, _pendingData: null, _pendingEncoding: '', server: undefined, _server: null, ssl: [TLSWrap], _requestCert: true, _rejectUnauthorized: true, parser: null, _httpMessage: [Circular], [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap], [Symbol(asyncId)]: 81, [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0, [Symbol(timeout)]: null, [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0, [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0, [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object] }, connection: TLSSocket { _tlsOptions: [Object], _secureEstablished: true, _securePending: false, _newSessionPending: false, _controlReleased: true, _SNICallback: null, servername: 'api.sendgrid.com', alpnProtocol: false, authorized: true, authorizationError: null, encrypted: true, _events: [Object], _eventsCount: 9, connecting: false, _hadError: false, _handle: [TLSWrap], _parent: null, _host: 'api.sendgrid.com', _readableState: [ReadableState], readable: true, domain: [Domain], _maxListeners: undefined, _writableState: [WritableState], writable: false, allowHalfOpen: false, _sockname: null, _pendingData: null, _pendingEncoding: '', server: undefined, _server: null, ssl: [TLSWrap], _requestCert: true, _rejectUnauthorized: true, parser: null, _httpMessage: [Circular], [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap], [Symbol(asyncId)]: 81, [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0, [Symbol(timeout)]: null, [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0, [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0, [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object] }, _header: 'PUT /v3/marketing/contacts HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nauthorization: Bearer HIDDEN\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.21.1\r\nHost: api.sendgrid.com\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n', _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput], agent: Agent { domain: null, _events: [Object], _eventsCount: 1, _maxListeners: undefined, defaultPort: 443, protocol: 'https:', options: [Object], requests: {}, sockets: [Object], freeSockets: {}, keepAliveMsecs: 1000, keepAlive: false, maxSockets: Infinity, maxFreeSockets: 256, maxCachedSessions: 100, _sessionCache: [Object] }, socketPath: undefined, timeout: undefined, method: 'PUT', insecureHTTPParser: undefined, path: '/v3/marketing/contacts', _ended: true, res: IncomingMessage { _readableState: [ReadableState], readable: false, domain: [Domain], _events: [Object], _eventsCount: 3, _maxListeners: undefined, socket: [TLSSocket], connection: [TLSSocket], httpVersionMajor: 1, httpVersionMinor: 1, httpVersion: '1.1', complete: true, headers: [Object], rawHeaders: [Array], trailers: {}, rawTrailers: [], aborted: false, upgrade: false, url: '', method: null, statusCode: 400, statusMessage: 'Bad Request', client: [TLSSocket], _consuming: false, _dumped: false, req: [Circular], responseUrl: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts', redirects: [] }, aborted: undefined, timeoutCb: null, upgradeOrConnect: false, parser: null, maxHeadersCount: null, _redirectable: Writable { _writableState: [WritableState], writable: true, domain: [Domain], _events: [Object], _eventsCount: 2, _maxListeners: undefined, _options: [Object], _ended: true, _ending: true, _redirectCount: 0, _redirects: [], _requestBodyLength: 0, _requestBodyBuffers: [], _onNativeResponse: [Function], _currentRequest: [Circular], _currentUrl: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts' }, [Symbol(isCorked)]: false, [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object: null prototype] { accept: [Array], 'content-type': [Array], authorization: [Array], 'user-agent': [Array], host: [Array] } }, response: { status: 400, statusText: 'Bad Request', headers: { server: 'nginx', date: 'Mon, 28 Dec 2020 01:39:11 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'content-length': '50', connection: 'close', 'x-amzn-requestid': '7cec2ea8-620a-4096-af97-c58c3f5f12d2', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'access-control-allow-headers': 'AUTHORIZATION, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl, X-Recaptcha, X-Request-Source', 'x-amz-apigw-id': 'YPWR7E1GvHcFVXg=', 'access-control-allow-methods': 'PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS', 'access-control-expose-headers': 'Link, Location', 'x-amzn-trace-id': 'Root=1-5fe9373f-69accb7255a34e6321797cf3;Sampled=0', 'x-envoy-upstream-service-time': '93', 'referrer-policy': 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'x-ratelimit-limit': '200', 'x-ratelimit-remaining': '199', 'x-ratelimit-reset': '49' }, config: { url: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts', method: 'put', headers: [Object], transformRequest: [Array], transformResponse: [Array], timeout: 0, adapter: [Function: httpAdapter], xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN', xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN', maxContentLength: -1, maxBodyLength: -1, validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus], body: [Object], data: undefined }, request: ClientRequest { domain: [Domain], _events: [Object], _eventsCount: 7, _maxListeners: undefined, output: [], outputEncodings: [], outputCallbacks: [], outputSize: 0, writable: true, _last: true, chunkedEncoding: false, shouldKeepAlive: false, useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true, sendDate: false, _removedConnection: false, _removedContLen: false, _removedTE: false, _contentLength: 0, _hasBody: true, _trailer: '', finished: true, _headerSent: true, socket: [TLSSocket], connection: [TLSSocket], _header: 'PUT /v3/marketing/contacts HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nauthorization: Bearer HIDDEN\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.21.1\r\nHost: api.sendgrid.com\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r\n', _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput], agent: [Agent], socketPath: undefined, timeout: undefined, method: 'PUT', insecureHTTPParser: undefined, path: '/v3/marketing/contacts', _ended: true, res: [IncomingMessage], aborted: undefined, timeoutCb: null, upgradeOrConnect: false, parser: null, maxHeadersCount: null, _redirectable: [Writable], [Symbol(isCorked)]: false, [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] }, data: { errors: [Array] } }, isAxiosError: true, toJSON: [Function: toJSON] }
```

Comment: "returns a bunch of nonsense to me" is not really helpful from a debugging perspective.  Please edit the question to explain more clearly what is not working the way you expect.  There should be enough information in the question that anyone can follow along and reproduce the observations that you make.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for the feedback. I just added the error logs

Comment: What do you expect the logs to contain otherwise?  If you look at just the log for the error message, it's telling you that the repsonse sent a 400 error, which means you made some sort of mistake in the request.

Comment: @DougStevenson I was hoping to get more detail about what kind of mistake. I have added some contacts successfully but other times it fails when I call the same exact code.

Comment: You should start by hard coding everything and don't depend on any variables.  Since we can't see the values of everything, it's not possible to know for sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out axios was failing. I switched to request and it worked like a charm. Here's my final code:

```
var request = require("request");
  var options = { method: 'PUT',
    url: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts',
    headers: 
    { 'content-type': 'application/json',
      authorization: 'Bearer ' + SEND_GRID_KEY},
    body: 
    { list_ids: [ 'eda0bc01-b098-4366-ad58-8bab03ec9b33' ],
      contacts: [
        {
          "email": e,
          "first_name": f,
          "last_name": l
        }
      ]
    },
    json: true };

  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    console.log(body);
  });
```

You can test out SendGrid's api and generate code here: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/contacts/add-or-update-a-contact